# Is Strimzi's operator for Apache Kafka still in beta version?

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, openshift, strimzi

Apache Kafka is available for Kubernetes by Strimzi, and on OpenShift by RedHat(AMQ Stream). RedHat's AMQ stream is based on Strimzi's Kafka Operator.

But when you define a Kafka resource like a broker or topic you start your YAML with something like this

`apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1`

It clearly says beta1, which means it is not production-ready.

Should I use Strimzi's Kafka operator on my Kubernetes/Openshift cluster?
Or is there any other option too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can say that Strimzi is really production-ready. There are already some users using it in production and you can see some of them on the website (https://strimzi.io/) and all of them in the ADOPTERS file here https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/blob/master/ADOPTERS.md

Sometimes happens, even in the Kubernetes land, that an API version is still beta while really stable.
We have an actual plan to finally move to CRD v1 and you can read about this in this Strimzi proposal got accepted and to be developed.

https://github.com/strimzi/proposals/blob/master/009-crd-v1-roadmap.md

Right now we are at 0.20.0 and we plan to have a kind of gate release on January 2021 and a final move to v1 in April.

Anyway, again, there is no need to wait for that time I can confirm that Strimzi is production ready.